# Google Apps Script findtext searchpattern format?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to pass in simple regex strings like

```
findText("/a/");
```

or

```
findText(/a/);
```

but it does not find anything. If I pass in only the text that works like this

```
findText("a");
```

How to pass regex strings in there?

Comment: I'm trying to scan through Google Text to find a space character but findText(" ") gives an error "Invalid argument: Search pattern".  I've tried "\s" but also does not work.  How to find a blank space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the String.search() method.

```
 function test(){
    var testString = "1212a1212";
    var results = testString.search(/a/);
    Logger.log(results);  //results = 4;
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

It's not super clear in the documentation of [`findText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern-replacement), but the documentation for [`replaceText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern-replacement) is more clear:

> > The search pattern is passed as a string, not a JavaScript regular expression object.

The example shown in the documentation of `replaceText` shows that your 3rd example is the correct one (where the search for `a` is shown as just the string, `"a"`.

`body.replaceText("^.*Apps ?Script.*$", "Apps Script");`

Obviously, `String.search()` will work here as well, but if you're looking to manipulate the attributes of the text, rather than just the string contents, using the built-in javascript function might leave you hanging.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use regex expressions with the [findText(searchPattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern) function however the expression needs to be in the [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) syntax.

For example if you wanted to do a case insensitive search for the word 'antevasin' you could specify

```
let searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText().findText( '(?i)antevasin' );
```

where (?i) turns on case-insensitive matching and would find 'Antevasin' in the document.

This [page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en) and this [one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/re2/+/refs/heads/master/re2/re2.h) have some examples and more detail.